# deploy report with subreport using jrs-rest-java-client API

Tags: java, rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using JasperReports Server with its jrs-rest-java-client API. When I access the remote server I want to inject sub reports  that the report should use. how can i do that?

Comment: `I want to inject sub reports that the report should use` - What do you mean? Your question is unclear..

Comment: Hi, i have one report with sub reports. I need to deploy the report that use sub reports. this sub reports are deploy in server. How can using jrs-rest-java-client API do that?

Comment: Did you create the reportUnit with the jrs-rest-java-client also? Please post what you have done so far.